# How to differentiate between a file not in SVN and one with no modifications

Tags: svn

For below two scenarios, svn stat does not return anything:-

- Present in the repo, but not locally modified
- Non-existent file (File which has not been created)

I want to know, how do I distinguish the two with an svn command.

Comment: What do you mean by "File does not exist"? Do you mean that it exists in the local workspace but is not committed to the svn repo?

Comment: Updated the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are the possible states of all files, with their outputs as provided by `svn status -v`:

- Part of the repository, but unchanged - `" "`
- Part of the repository, changed - `"M"`
- Part of the repository, but not present - `"!"`
- Being added to the repository - `"A"`
- Being removed from the repository - `"D"`
- Not part of the repository - `"?"`

So use the 'verbose' option and you'll get everything you need.